# Inkwell / Gesture Detector On Hold and On Release

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make a container that contain image
and when i hold changed the image
and when release it change back to the first image

and have transition
[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLwWVbv3xDQ]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLwWVbv3xDQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change image with `setState`

```
String imgAssetRes;

GestureDetector(
  child: Image.asset(imgAssetRes),
  onTapDown: (_){
    setState(() {
      imgAssetRes = "[image_on_press]";
    });
  },
  onTapUp: (_){
    setState(() {
      imgAssetRes = "[image_on_release]";
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: and how to add transition or animation ex: fade ??

Comment: You can use `FadeInImage` - it contains fade animation

Comment: where? i already try but failed, and sometime both image disappear

i want to make something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/bg3At.gif

Comment: So you have to paste your code and describe what wrong with it

Comment: Your question is about changing image on tap and release. Regarding vibration it has to be another question